# ¿En Android hay algún tipo de objeto para guardar posición GPS?

Tags: java, android

¿Existe algún tipo de variable o objeto en Java (Android) para guardar posiciones de GPS, es decir cada punto se compone de latitud y el otro longitud?

Por ejemplo poder guardar la [localización de Madrid](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html):

```
Latitude:  40.416775
Longitude: -3.703790
```

y que permite agregar varias localizaciones, como una lista.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se añade un simple ejemplo de uso y como añadir en base a la respuesta de [@Fabricio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2640/en-java-hay-alg%C3%BAn-tipo-de-objeto-para-guardar-posici%C3%B3n-gps/2641#2641):

```
LatLng pos = new LatLng(40.416775, -3.703790);
double lat = pos.latitude; //getLatitude
double lng = pos.longitude;//getLongitude
```

Puedes añadirla así (selecionando la revisión/versión que quieras):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //..
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
}
```

Puedes consultar para mas información aquí: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

---

Sobre la segunda parte de tu pregunta puedes crear un `array` o `list` o lo que necesites del objeto `LatLng`.

Simple ejemplo basado sobre `pointY[]`, y `pointX[]`(Los puntos estos son numeros aleatorios):

```
double pointY[]={10.0000,10.5000,100.3000,100.2222}
double pointX[]={3.0000, 7.3333, 9.1111,  9.11111}

List<LatLng> puntos=new ArrayList<LatLng>();

for (int i = 0 ; i < pointX.length; i++){
    puntos.add(new LatLng(pointX[i],pointY[i]));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

El Objeto que mencionas se encuentra en la librería de Google Maps para Android y es `LatLng`, si no estás utilizando esta librería puedes crear una clase que esté compuesta por una Latitud(`double`) y una Longitud(`double`).

Aquí te dejo el link de la [documentación de la clase](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng).

Comment: bajo mi punto de vista su respuesta es correcta en cuanto al uso de LatLng, pero usted comenta de crear una clase propia, la idea no es mala, pero puede traer errores o confuciones si usas tu propia clase (en la creacion de la logica), y despues decides que quieres usarla como parametro en las clases de google, que lo que espera es un LatLng, y tendrias que rescribir codigo. Podrias aclarar eso en tu respuesta para posibles futuros visitantes si quieres Saludos