# Detectar si un punto de un mapa esta dentro de un circle

Tags: android, google-maps

Alguien sabe si es posible detectar si un punto con latitud y longitud esta dentro de un circle. Todo esto desarrollado en Android.

Comment: Sí, es posible.

Comment: Podrías intentar aplicar un poco de geometría...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[¿En Android hay algún tipo de objeto para guardar posición GPS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2640/en-android-hay-alg%C3%BAn-tipo-de-objeto-para-guardar-posici%C3%B3n-gps/2642#2642)

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng#public-constructor-summary

```
LatLng pos = new LatLng(40.416775, -3.703790);
double lat = pos.latitude; //getLatitude
double lng = pos.longitude;//getLongitude
```

supongamos que este es su punto `pos`

---

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle#example

```
 GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add a circle in Sydney
 Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689))
     .radius(10000)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

si este fuera su circulo `circle` (es del ejemplo de Sydney Australia del link superior)

---

> http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,
>   double, double, double, float[])

```
float[] disResultado = new float[2];

Location.distanceBetween( pos.latitude, pos.longitude,
                          circle.getCenter().latitude, 
                          circle.getCenter().longitude, 
                          disResultado);

if(disResultado[0] > circle.getRadius()){
    Log Fuera
} else {
    Log Dentro
}
```

Usted puede usar la clase `Location` para hacer los caculos

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/location/Location.html

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds#nested-class-summary

Comment: hey no conocía este método distanceBetween() y veo que esta desde API level 1 =0 !, muy buen aporte!!!

Comment: @Elenasys yo cuando lo encontre, me alegre la verdad. Saludos